# If <div> is active, get data tag and select from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `<div>`s on a slider that when a `<div>` is active, it has the class `.is-selected`. These `<div>`s also have a data tag called `data-ID` whereby it has an `ID` related to a dropdown select. I'd like to be able to automatically choose the select option depending on what `<div>` is active, but I'm not sure where to get the `ID` from and where to pass it to?

```
    <div class="cell" style="position: absolute; left: 0%;">
        <div data-ID="Item1" class="item">
            <h2>Option 1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0%;">
        <div data-ID="Item2" class="item">
            <h2>Option 2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: paste your code as well

Answer (score 0):

So select the div, read the attribute, set the value.

```js
var selected = $("div.is-selected > div[data-ID]"),
  dataId = selected.data("id");

$("#mySelect").val(dataId);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Pick</option>
  <option value="Item1">one</option>
  <option value="Item2">two</option>
</select>

<div class="cell" style="position: absolute; left: 0%;">
  <div data-ID="Item1" class="item">
    <h2>Option 1</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cell is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0%;">
  <div data-ID="Item2" class="item">
    <h2>Option 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```